# Garbage reading from NSInputStream

Tags: ios, buffer, inputstream

Im using input streams to communicate with a POS device.

When i send the first request the response is normal. The problem comes when i send the second request because the second response is shorter than first one and that content is still in the stream. So i get the following:

First response:

```
<response>A really big response with much more things inside</response>
```

Second response;

```
<response>A not so big response</response>more things inside</response>
```

I do the following:

1) Open the streams

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)host, [port intValue], &readStream, &writeStream);
iStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
oStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[iStream setDelegate:self];
[oStream setDelegate:self];
[iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[iStream open];
[oStream open];
```

2) then i write my request:

```
[oStream write:(uint8_t *)[request UTF8String] maxLength:[request length]];
```

3) when the response arrives i capture it and send it to the parser:

```
uint8_t buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
[iStream read:buffer maxLength:MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1];
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)buffer];
free(buffer);

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *ret =[SimpleXMLConverter dictionaryForXMLString:response error:&error];
```

After this, i tried to close the streams and open them again before sending the second request

Thanks and regards

PS: its not a blocking issue because i can get the correct substring, but i dont understand why its happening

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @Larme sure. 1 second, I will edit the post

Comment: @Larme already edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `buffer` string is not `\0`(NULL) terminated.
Maybe `uint8_t buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};` will solve your current problem.

However, you should consider one response could be longer than `MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1`.
Even if a response is shorter than it, `read:maxLength:` is not guaranteed to read all data at once. You must check the returned value and received data has entire response.

Moreover, DO NOT `free(buffer)`, because `free()` is only for `malloc()`ed memory, not for auto variables.